# The difference between "allow" and "enable"

Tags: word-meaning, word-difference

Please, clarify me the difference between the verbs ***to allow*** and ***to enable***.
What are the peculiarities in their meanings especially in formal and technical context?
As example, I have such context

> Thereby it will **enable/allow** to change the date of planned work in case of
>   serious complaints from other teams related to business necessity.

But I would appreciate more broad explanation of meaning distinctions, beyond the context I've given.
Thank you for assistance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Semantically, ***permit*** would convey exactly the same meaning as ***allow / enable*** here, but personally I don't like this "intransitive" usage (where it's unspecified ***who*** is enabled / allowed / permitted to do something). It's a relatively recent usage, as show by [this NGram...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=will%20allow%20*%20to%20calculate&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cwill%20allow%20%2A%20to%20calculate%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwill%20allow%20us%20to%20calculate%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwill%20allow%20you%20to%20calculate%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwill%20allow%20one%20to%20calculate%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

As pointed out above, I see no possibility of *any* of those three verbs conveying any different meaning. Idiomatically, ***allow*** is probably more common in such contexts, but that doesn't mean the alternatives are in any sense "incorrect" - *providing it's used **transitively** (with an "object" such as **us, you, one,...***

***But*** whereas the "intransitive" version with ***allow*** merely "grates" on my ear, I'd be more inclined to say that such usages really *are* "syntactically invalid" with ***enable / permit***. So if you *insist* on not specifying who is allowed/permitted/enabled to do something, you should probably stick with ***allow*** (but I at least will always tend to assume "non-native speaker" when I see/hear that usage).

---

Offhand I can't think of many contexts where there's any significant difference in meaning between ***to allow / permit / enable*** [someone to do something], but perhaps one might argue that being ***enabled*** more strongly implies *having an (internally-based) **ability/capacity** to do something*, whereas being ***allowed / permitted*** more strongly alludes to *not being prevented from doing something by (externally-based) constraints*. Thus one might favour...

> *His well-developed muscles **enabled** him to lift very heavy dumbbell weights*
>    over
>    *His well-developed muscles **allowed** him to lift very heavy dumbbell weights*

...but in practice I don't think many people would make that distinction. On the other hand, only ***allow / permit*** can really be used where the intended sense is very clearly that of *being given permission / having (existing, rule-based) constraints lifted*, as in...

> *The teacher **allowed** the children to leave school early on the last day of term*
>    (Where ***permitted*** would also work, but ***enabled*** normally<sup>1</sup> wouldn't.)

---

<sup>1</sup> As an example of an "unusual" context where ***enabled*** could work for that last example...

> *The teacher **enabled** the children to leave school early on the last day of term **by arranging for the school bus to leave at 3 o'clock instead of its normal 4 o'clock departure time**.*

Answer (score 1):

The usual distinction between **allow** and **enable** is that **allow** means "to not prohibit something, to let it happen, to remove any constraint that would prevent something from happening" and **enable** means "to make something possible".

When describing a feature of some tool, **allow** is often used to mean "make something possible  because it is now much easier to do, thanks to this feature", its prior difficulty having been a constraint that made it not really possible to do, at least not without an unlikely amount of effort being devoted to the task.

Answer (score 0):

If you *allow X*, you are A) not preventing X from happening and/or B) typically implying you approve it.  But you are not doing anything.

If you *enable X*, you are actively doing something so that X can happen.